# Display multiple datas from same table from mysql using listview

Tags: asp.net

I am using a listview to display datas from 3 tables in mysql.
 My tables are,

```
theatredet(theaterid,theatername,locationid)
location(locationid,locationname)
screendet(screenname,theaterid,seatsavailable)
```

I want to display datas from screendet on the basis of theaterid from the table theatredet,i can only able to disply single data from screendet,there are multiple datas on that table with respect of theaterid.

My query is,

```
string query = "SELECT `theatredetails`.*,`Location`.`LocationName`,
        `screendetails`.`ScreenName`,`screendetails`.`SeatsAvailable` 
        FROM `theatredetails`INNER JOIN `screendetails` 
        ON `screendetails`.`TheatreDetailsId` = `theatredetails`.`TheatreDetailsId` 
        INNER JOIN `location` ON `location`.`LocationId`=`theatredetails`.`LocationId`;";
```

My aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ScreenName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("SeatsAvailable") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: why do you need locationId in your query? may be that is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already tested your query on MySql and it is returning intended number of rows.

You can populate your listview using the following code (I am using SqlDataSource to bind the ListView, you can use any other method)

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstviewScreens" runat="server" DataSourceID="ScreensSqlDataSource" >

<LayoutTemplate>

       <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" >

           <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
           </tr>
        </table>

 </LayoutTemplate>

 <ItemTemplate>
     <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF;">
       <td>
        <strong>Theater Name:</strong><asp:Label ID="lblTheaterName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("theatername") %>' />
        <br />
        <strong>Screen Name:</strong><asp:Label ID="lblScreenName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ScreenName") %>' />
         <br />
         <strong>Seats Available</strong><asp:Label ID="lblSeatsAvailable" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SeatsAvailable") %>' />
       </td>
     </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ScreensSqlDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Your connection String" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT theatredetails.*,Location.LocationName,
    screendetails.ScreenName,screendetails.SeatsAvailable 
    FROM theatredetails INNER JOIN screendetails 
    ON screendetails.TheatreDetailsId = theatredetails.TheatreDetailsId 
    INNER JOIN location ON location.LocationId=theatredetails.LocationId">

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This will output your data in tabular format, however you can customize LayoutTemplate to change the generated html, even you can use GroupTemplate to group the data.